# Sql error with backquotes, says there's a syntax error at or near "`"

Tags: sql, heroku, syntax-error

I'm trying to load a database into Heroku from a sql file, however I get a syntax error from back quotes / backticks.

```
heroku pg:psql < backup.sql
```

Outputs this error:

```
syntax error at or near "`"
```

Why is that? Aren't backquotes valid?

I can find/replace them with something else if that would be good to try.

Comment: Show us your SQL!!!  But no, backquotes are *not* necessarily legal in all SQL's.  Or perhaps the actual syntax error is *near* your backquote.  Look here for PostgreSQL syntax: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Comment: Backquotes are used in MySQL for delimiting identifiers (table names, column names, etc.) but this is not standard SQL, and it's not supported by PostgreSQL. PG uses double-quotes for the equivalent purpose.

Answer (score -1):

are you restoring from a postgresql system or another db software such mySQL? 
can you search your backup.sql file for the back-ticks and post that section of your file?
it would help to know if your back-ticks are in the column field names or in the data portion of the SQL statement.